# al día vs por día vs cada día

Tags: vocabulario

My quick question is just what is the difference between the phrases in the title(al día por día and cada día)? They all mean something similar- everyday, per day etc.
So how do I know when to use which?

Thanks.

Comment: Cada día is for every day. 5 veces por día and una vez al día are usually preceded by a number of times something occurs. Although you can say Dos veces cada día, it is not as prevalent as the other two with a number of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the other answer that all three mean the same thing. However, "cada día" is more autonomous as an adverbial. While all three can be used in phrases containing a numeral:

- **tres** veces al día (three times a day)
- **tres** veces por día
- **tres** veces cada día

only "cada día" can be used as a standalone adverbial (in which case it is equivalent to "todos los días" -- every day):

- **Cada día** encuentro un nuevo motivo para vivir. (Every day I find a new reason to be alive.) (In this case, "al día" and "por día" don't work.)

Answer (score 2):

All three options have the same meanings and can be used in the same context.

There's no difference between them!